# How to link multiple libraries reside in different subfolders in CMake and using namespace?

Tags: c++, cmake

[image]

I have started to learn CMake framework to build cmake recently and started a dummy project to understand how it works.

My project structure is as shown in the image. The CMakeLists.txt at the root level (myapp->CMakeLists.txt) is shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(dummyCMake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -Wall -Wextra")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-o0")

add_subdirectory(libs)

include_directories(includes)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

get_filename_component(parent_dir ../ ABSOLUTE)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC uiolibs)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC mathlibs)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/uiolibs/includes"
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mathlibs/includes"
)
```

sub directories CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
file(GLOB sources "src/*cpp")
message(${sources}) #for debugging
add_library(uiolibs  STATIC ${sources})
```

Getting linking error
**undefined reference to `mathlibs::AddInit(int, int)**

**undefined reference to `userinput::getInit()**

Any suggestion to fix this issue (or in general on cmake framework) will be appreciated.

The project code folder: [github link](https://github.com/palasg/cmakedummy)

Comment: Are you sure your github code is latest? I'm getting cc1plus: error: too many filenames given.  Type cc1plus --help for usage

Comment: @harry yes it is. FYI, steps I am following: 1. Download 2. mkdir build 3. cd build 4. cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. 5. make :: throwing unknown reference to AddInt, getInt().

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you linked your code here because it's not a cmake problem.

```
using namespace userinput;
int getInit() {}
```

This doesn't define `userinput::getInit` as you expect, it just defines `getInit`.

Comment: Thank you @yyyy, it is working. However, my second question would be if I want to using namespace, how would I do?

Comment: @palas You can either put your function in `namespace userinput { ... }` like what you do in the head files, or write `int userinput::getInit() {}`